# How do I push local folder into new Github repository?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my local code(my portfolio into my new Github repository.
So created new repository.
It says:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/ex_username/ex_name.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Before pushing this repository, I was working on remote repository(which is another repository on my github) by making changes etc.
I used to push: `git push origin main`

The issue is when I am trying to push my new local folder(which is my portfolio) , *the previous repository that I was working on github* **being pushed together**

How can I push my existing folder separately into my new repository?

Here is a clarification, I was working on these repos on Github:
[image]

and here is next one. This repo is in **Desktop/Project/20172018**:
[image]

Currently I have "My Portfolio" folder that I want to push into new repo on Github. When I created new repo and pushing the local folder, then above existing repos are being pushed together:
[image]

**What I want is this, just My Portfolio repo**
[image]

Comment: what is the previous folder? sorry not really clear to me....

Comment: @OznOg It is another repository in my github. So I was working in existing repo in Github and while trying to add new repo and push local folder, then previous folders are being pushed together

Comment: What does it mean to be "pushed together"? Can you explain more about what you're trying to do and what you're seeing on your screen, things like git commands and the output? It isn't altogether clear what the problem is here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen added with pictures for clarification

Comment: @OznOg added pics of repos

Comment: Which directory is your git remote configured in? Is it configured in the directory that contains "My Portfolio" and the other directory? Or do you have one configured for "My Portfolio" and different one for the other directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new GitHub repo they provide you with 2 option of pushing data:

1. create a new repository...
2. push an existing repository

You chose the second one, but the folder that contains all your projects is not a git repository yet, that's why you are having trouble pushing data.

Try doing the steps provided in the first option as to create a new repository for all your existing projects.

Answer (score 3):

First In local, in your new directory initiate git and then add and commit files to git using the below commands.

- git init
- git add .
- git commit -m "initial commit"

Second, create a new empty repo and then use the below commands in your project terminal to push the local repo to the remote repository.

- git remote add origin git@github.com:git-hub-name/your-project.git

incase if you're not on the branch main execute the below command (optional)

- git branch -M main

Finally

- git push -u origin main

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git checkout -b <branch-name>`, this should create a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create an empty repository on GitHub with the `same name` as your folder.

Second, you need to initialize your folder as a Git repository and connect it to the GitHub repository. You can do this by opening a terminal and navigating to your folder. Then, type the following commands:

```bash
git init # This will initialize your folder as a Git repository
git remote add origin https://github.com/your-username/your-repository-name.git # This will link your local repository to the GitHub repository
```

Third, you need to add and commit your files to the local repository and push them to the GitHub repository. You can do this by typing the following commands:

```
git add . # This will add all the files in your folder to the staging area
git commit -m "Your commit message" # This will commit your changes with a message
git push -u origin master # This will push your changes to the master branch of the GitHub repository
```

Finally, you can check your GitHub repository online and see if your files are uploaded successfully.
`Note:Folder and repository name must be same`